# Spring-Data Mysql cannot find the name in the DB

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring-Data Mysql, I created a little method to make it give me a name from a list of names, it returns me the name with the oldest entry date. Unfortunately when I do the get it returns me this :

```
D:\>curl -G localhost:8080/demo/first  -d name=Biagio
{"timestamp":"2020-10-02T09:29:33.704+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message
```

I've tried them all a little but so far I can't be successful. Below is the method and the relative controller

UserRepositoryImpl.java

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql;






import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {
    
    private final EntityManager em;
    
    public UserRepositoryImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.em = entityManager;
    }


    @Override
    public User findFirstByName(String name) {
            CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = builder.createQuery(User.class);
            Root<User> root = criteria.from(User.class);
            criteria.select(root).where(builder.equal(root.get("name"), name));
            criteria.orderBy(builder.asc(root.get("timestamp")));
            TypedQuery<User> query = em.createQuery(criteria).setMaxResults(1);
            return query.getSingleResult();
            
        }
    
    
    @Override
//  per la creazione//
    public void create(User entity) {
        em.persist(entity); 
    }
           
 }
```

mainController.java

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql;






import javax.persistence.NoResultException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller 
@RequestMapping(path="/demo") 
public class MainController {
  @Autowired 
         
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @Transactional
  @PostMapping(path="/add")
  public @ResponseBody String addNewUser (@RequestParam String name
      , @RequestParam String email,@RequestParam String surname) 
  {
 

    User n = new User();
    n.setName(name);
    n.setSurname(surname);
    n.setEmail(email);
    userRepository.create(n);
    return "Saved";
  }



 


  @GetMapping("/first")
   User one(@RequestParam String name) {
   System.out.print(name);
   try { return userRepository.findFirstByName(name); 
   } catch (NoResultException nre) { 
       return null; } 
  }
}
```

I add User and UserRepository.java for everything

User.java

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.Instant;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity 
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;
 
  public String name;

  private String email;
  
  private String surname;
  

  
  
  @Column(name="stmp", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP (6)")
  Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.from(Instant.now());

public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

 public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
return timestamp;
}


 public String getSurname() {
     return surname;
 }
 
 public  void setSurname(String surname) {
     this.surname = surname;
 }
 
  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql;





import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface UserRepository {
    User findFirstByName(String name);
    void create(User entity);
    
}
```

EDIT: I insert the database referenced by this small project:

```
+----+---------------------+--------+----------------------------+---------+
| id | email               | name   | stmp                       | surname |
+----+---------------------+--------+----------------------------+---------+
| 32 | mirketto90@yahoo.it | Mirko  | 2020-10-01 12:31:47.827000 | NULL    |
| 36 | biagio@gmail.com    | Biagio | 2020-10-01 16:31:31.687000 | Vaso    |
| 37 | biagio@gmail.com    | Biagio | 2020-10-01 16:31:50.077000 | Vaso    |
| 38 | biagio@gmail.com    | Biagio | 2020-10-01 18:35:45.992000 | Vaso    |
+----+---------------------+--------+----------------------------+---------+
```

Comment: I think ```UserRepository``` needs to implement one of the spring data repository classes, ```CrudRepository```  might be a good start, you will need to give the chossen interface the entity type and id type as type parameters.  Can you share the database schema with us, it might help us to answer your question?

Comment: Hey Jacket! Please check out how to create [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Gavin I can't use Crud, I need to create the method myself, I entered the reference db

Comment: @Ava_Katushka thanks for the advice my friend, I'll try to fix everything. It's just that I've been messing up with this problem for days and didn't notice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to verify the endpoint `localhost:8080/demo/first?name=Biagio` using your browser, as it submits GET requests by default.

I managed to reproduce this issue, you should remove the class-level mapping and provide full path on the method in `MainController`:

```java
@RestController
public class MainController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional
    @PostMapping("/demo/add")
    public @ResponseBody String addNewUser (
            @RequestParam String name,
            @RequestParam String email,
            @RequestParam String surname) 
    {
        User n = new User();
        n.setName(name);
        n.setSurname(surname);
        n.setEmail(email);
        userRepository.create(n);
        return "Saved";
    }

    @GetMapping("/demo/first")
    public User one(@RequestParam String name) {
        System.out.print(name);
        return userRepository.findFirstByName(name); 
    }
}
```

The following `curl` requests should succeed:

```
curl -X GET localhost:8080/demo/first?name=Biagio
curl -G localhost:8080/demo/first?name=Biagio
curl -G localhost:8080/demo/first -d name=Biagio
```

**Update**
The following fix is also working without leading slashes in the method-level mappings:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/demo") // trailing slash optional, could be "/demo/"
public class MainController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional
    @PostMapping("add") // no leading slash
    public @ResponseBody String addNewUser (/* ... */) {
    // ...
    }

    @GetMapping("first") // no leading slash
    public User one(@RequestParam String name) {
        return userRepository.findFirstByName(name); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't change anything, can it be an error in the method?

Comment: YOU ARE GREAT! Thank you so much Alex, you saved me! hope you have a nice day, thanks again!

Comment: @Jacket, if the question was helpful, I'd appreciate if you could also upvote it :)

Answer (score 1):

the first things I see are the following:

- Your method for `/demo/first` is not public.
- The proper way to call this endpoint should be `curl localhost:8080/demo/first?name=Biagio -H "Accept: application/json"`

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't change anything, can it be an error in the method?